# Count the Number of Unique Character Types based on Date in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe titled `FilteredData` with *many* columns. Specifically, there are two columns I am interested in: `Date` and `Sale number.`

I want to group all `Sale number` entries by dates. `Date` is a date-type field, and `Sale number` is a character-type field. If I'm not mistaken, I think these types are the reason why other Q&As on S.O. haven't been much help to me.

How can I do this?

I've tried the following:

```
aggregate(FilteredData$`Sale number`, by FilteredData$Date, FUN = count)
group_by(FilteredData$`Sale number`, FilteredData$Date)
```

Neither worked, and neither did the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3856609) when I tried it.

I tried the following:

```
library(sqldf)
Freq = sqldf('SELECT Date, COUNT('Sale Number') FROM FilteredData GROUP BY Date')
```

and it surprisingly worked. However, is there a way to obtain this result without having to use SQL syntax, i.e. something "purely" in R?

Comment: Maybe just `table(FilteredData$FundedDate)` or `rowSums(table(FilteredData$FundedDate, FilteredData$FundedDate) > 0)` for unique counts by date.

Comment: @lmo I've been banging my head around trying to get what you just suggested. Thank you

Comment: I notice that `by FilteredData$FundedDate` cannot work.   Did you have an = in there?

Comment: @G5W, why can it not work?

Comment: or `rowSums(table(FilteredData$FundedDate, FilteredData$\`Sale number\`) > 0)` for unique counts by date. (typo in previous comment).

Comment: `by FilteredData$FundedDate`    won't parse.   You need `by = FilteredData$FundedDate `

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table` as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(FilteredData)

FilteredData[ , uniqueN(`Sale number`), by = Date]
```

I'm not sure if `dplyr` has a tailored function for this... you may just want `` length(unique(`Sale number`)) `` there.

Comment: regarding your note on the bottom- you're correct, it was a typo on my end. Fixed now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear... So you want to group by *date* and then count the number of non-duplicate entries within a date?

`dplyr` can do this:

```
FilteredData %>% # take filtered data
  group_by(FundedDate) %>% # group by the date
  subset(!duplicated('Sale number')) %>% # remove rows that are duplicated sales numbers 
  count('Sale number') # count sales numbers
```

Comment: Hello Mark, I just edited my question- let me know if my fixing the variable names clear things up a bit. Thanks

Comment: Gotcha. Does my answer help? That's how I do grouped counts.